# How to get cross platform absolute relative file path?

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm having issues loading files by thier path over my code which runs over Windows (local test and development) and Linux (CI CD).

While running my code locally in Windows, the file path relative works fine, when my code is running over Linux it turns to a mess and returns an Error: `No such file or directory`

Is there such a code in Python which is cross platform to solve it ?

My code is like this:

```
def get_event_json_file_path(fileName):
    file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
    file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, "events/" + fileName)
    return file_path
```

Is there a code to get the classpath of the folder ?

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: And of course, you can use the functions in `os.path` and below to platform-independently handle paths, make absolute ones relative, etc.

Comment: If you use relative paths and slashes (not backslashes) as separators, it should work on all operating systems.

Comment: code added, please look

Comment: Jesus christ... that answer where you copied `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))` from should be deleted. Such a fundamental lack of understanding...

Comment: how could I get the classpath of the folder ?

Comment: Use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` (without the quotes) or `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))`

Comment: these are the same, if I would distinguish between OS types using is statement, will it be good enough ?

Comment: Don't hardcode path seperators.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to code this function:

```
def get_relative_file_path(file_dir_path, fileName):
    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(dir, file_dir_path,fileName)
    return file_path
```

Usage:

```
get_relative_file_path('../resources/', "restCallBodySchema.json")
```